# importing shape file to openLayers bing map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, bing-maps

i want to import my **shapefile** into my map using **openlayers Bing.Map** but after import my shape file in map  i can not zoom out or zoom in in my map and it looks like crushing

i am using openlayers7.1 in my code .  i set drag and drop event for importing shape file in to map . this code can handle **shape.shp** **shape.dbf**  shape.sbn and ... as **shape.zip** file
the rest of code can be found https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html here but for working you need to replace your API Key where you can see `API Key` in the code .

i need Sample code to fix this. thanks

```
import BingMaps from 'ol/source/BingMaps';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import View from 'ol/View';
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import vectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';

const place =[59.6067,36.2972];
const styles = [
 'RoadOnDemand',
 'Aerial',
 'AerialWithLabelsOnDemand',
 'CanvasDark',
 'OrdnanceSurvey',
];
const layers = [];
let i, ii;
for (i = 0, ii = styles.length; i < ii; ++i) {
 layers.push(
   new TileLayer({
     visible: false,
     preload: Infinity,
     source: new BingMaps({
       key: "API Key",
       imagerySet: styles[i],
       // use maxZoom 19 to see stretched tiles instead of the BingMaps
       // "no photos at this zoom level" tiles
       // maxZoom: 19
     }),
   })
 );
}
const map = new Map({
 layers: layers,
 target: 'map',
 view: new View({
   center: fromLonLat(place),
   zoom: 8,
 }),
});

const select = document.getElementById('layer-select');
function onChange() {
 const style = select.value;
 for (let i = 0, ii = layers.length; i < ii; ++i) {
   layers[i].setVisible(styles[i] === style);
 }
}
select.addEventListener('change', onChange);
onChange();
```

```
const featureStyle = new ol.style.Style({
 stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: 'red',
   width: 1
 })
});

map.getViewport().addEventListener('dragover', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
});

map.getViewport().addEventListener('drop',shpShow);

function shpShow(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 const files = event.dataTransfer.files;
 for (let i = 0, ii = files.length; i < ii; ++i) {
   const file = files.item(i);
   loadshp({url: file, encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(geojson) {
     const features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(
       geojson,
       { featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection() }
     );
     const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
       features: features
     });
     map.addLayer(
       new ol.layer.Vector({
         source: vectorSource,
         style: featureStyle
       })
     );
     map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
   });
 }
}
```

```
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/lib/jszip.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/lib/jszip-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.1/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/preprocess.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/preview.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using `loadshp` from https://github.com/gipong/shp2geojson.js?

A dropped file needs to be read by a FileReader, in your case as a dataUrl

```
   const file = files.item(i);
   const reader = new FileReader();
   reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
     loadshp({url: reader.result, encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(geojson) {
       ....
       ....
     });
   });
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: yes, but reading zip file is done right . and it shows in openlayer simple map correctly , but when i use bing map , map is not work correctly

Comment: Does the map appear correctly before you drop files?

Comment: yes it does ...

Answer (score 0):

very good question
When we import the .shp files, the map is not refreshed again.
I had this challenge for a long time and still this problem exists in my codes.
Thanks if anyone has the ability to solve this challenge.